# neo4j / cypher - how to add a new "synonym" to a collection of synonyms?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am just starting out with neo4j and cypher. I am building a database to store names and synonyms for different chemicals. The way I currently do this is something like this:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (flow:Flow) ASSERT flow.name IS UNIQUE;
CREATE (a:Flow {name: "Ethene"})-[:synonym]->(b:Flow {name: "Ethylene"});
```

(The `-->` syntax is required by cypher syntax even though synonym is a bidirectional relationship).

Now-- say I want to add a new flow which is a synonym to both,

```
CREATE (c:Flow {name: "C2H4"})-[:synonym]->(b:Flow {name: "Ethylene"})
```

After that, I will have 3 nodes in a linear relationship `(a)-[:synonym]->(b)<-[:synonym]-(c)`. But synonymy is transitive, so the graph of synonyms should really be complete (the `a-[:synonym]-c` relationship is missing)

Is there a way to automatically create a `:synonym` relationship to a node *and* all that node's synonyms?

The following seems to work, except it feels clumsy and also is not idempotent (if it's run again, it creates a `c-->c` relationship):

```
// create a new synonym to 'Ethylene' with the name 'C2H04'
MATCH (j:Flow {name:"Ethylene"})-[:synonym]-(k)
WITH j,k
MERGE (c:Flow {name:"C2H04"})-[:synonym]->(j)
MERGE (c)-[:synonym]->(k)
```

Is there a better way to create these relationships?  Alternately, is there a way to collapse all the synonym relationships so that a query will return all synonyms of a node even if they are not directly connected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to change the model. Let's add an intermediate node such as "synonym" to connects all synonyms:

```
(S:Synonym)
(A1:Flow {name: "Ethene"})-[:synonym]->(S)
(A2:Flow {name: "Ethylene"})-[:synonym]->(S)
(A3:Flow {name: "C2H4"})-[:synonym]->(S)
```

Example query for creating:

```
MERGE (A1:Flow {name: "Ethene"})
MERGE (A2:Flow {name: "Ethylene"})
MERGE (A3:Flow {name: "C2H4"})
MERGE (A1)-[:synonym]->(S:Synonym)
MERGE (A2)-[:synonym]->(S)
MERGE (A3)-[:synonym]->(S)

MERGE (A11:Flow {name: "Ferrum"})
MERGE (A12:Flow {name: "Iron"})
MERGE (A13:Flow {name: "Fe"})
MERGE (A11)-[:synonym]->(S2:Synonym)
MERGE (A12)-[:synonym]->(S2)
MERGE (A13)-[:synonym]->(S2)
```

Sample query for get all group of synonyms:

```
MATCH (S:Synonym) WITH S
MATCH (S)<-[:synonym]-(F:Flow)
WITH S, collect(F) as synonyms
RETURN synonyms
```

Sample query for get all synonyms for chemical:

```
MATCH (A:Flow {name:'Ethene'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (A)-[:synonym]->(S:Synonym)<-[:synonym]-(F:Flow)
RETURN A as chemical, collect(F) as synonyms
```

Add new chemical as synonym to exist chemical:

```
MATCH (A:Flow {name:'C2H4'})
  MERGE (A)-[:synonym]->(S:Synonym)
  MERGE (New:Flow {name:'Aethylen'})
  MERGE (New)-[:synonym]->(S)
```

***Update***:

If you do not want to change your model, you can use a query with a variable path length to get all synonyms for chemical:

```
MATCH (A:Flow {name: "Ethylene"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (A)-[:synonym*]-(F:Flow)
RETURN A as chemical, collect(F) as synonyms
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. So in this case, there would be a new 'synonym' node for every distinct chemical... I think I can work with that. I will consider the suggestion

Comment: I do like the variable path length- didn't know about that- but this thread has shown me I need to do more reading before I settle on a data model

Answer (score 1):

It would be much simpler overall if all the synonyms for the same chemical resided within a single node. For example:

```
(:Flow {names: ["Ethylene", "Ethene", "C2H4"]})
```

Comment: I think that's not a good idea: a synonym for a chemical compound usually brings a lot of additional information associated with this synonym (language, notation, nomenclature, a reference to an external database and an identifier in the database, and much more).

Comment: This doesn't quite work for me because of the data I'm working with- the same chemical might appear in different databases with different information and under different names- I want to be able to link the two entries without collapsing them together.